# What is the zsh equivalent of bash's !$ (Bang Dollar)?

Tags: bash, zsh

In bash I can do

```
ls foo/
[...]
echo !$
foo/
```

What is the zsh equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like exactly the same thing to me.

```
% ls foo/ 
......
% echo !$
echo foo/
foo/
```